# VS Code Remote Development using a docker container hosted in the cloud

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

With the VS Code extension [Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) I can develop inside a container that is spun up on my local computer via Docker Desktop.

Is there any way to develop inside a container hosted on Azure, AWS, Google Cloud, or any other cloud system instead?

I can't use Docker Desktop locally because I'm on a Macbook Pro with Apple Silicon, meaning that Docker does not work the same way as it would on an Intel chip.

###### UPDATE 2021-12-04:

I solved the issue by using [GitHub Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces)

Comment: Do you have access to the machine that hosts the docker container? If that's the case, you might be able to use docker context.

Comment: @Aviv Lo yes I do, I have access to everything. How would I do that?

Comment: I'll write a proper answer after work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker context`

It forwards the remote docker socket via ssh to your local machine

```sh
docker context create NAME_OF_THE_CONTEXT --docker "host=ssh://$SERVER_USER_NAME@$SERVER_IP"
```

Use the context

```sh
docker context use NAME_OF_THE_CONTEXT
```

Now you can run docker commands in your local terminal that will be executed on the remote host.

So now you can connect to remote containers via VSCode as if the containers are running remotely.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to create a Docker Droplet on DigitalOcean. Connect to it via `docker context` as you described. I validated that I was in the right context via `docker info`.

However, when I use the VS Code command _Reopen in Container_ I get the following error:
`docker: error during connect: Post "http://docker/v1.24/containers/create": command [ssh -l root -- <IP> docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 255, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: Let me try this locally as well.

Comment: @Martin can you ssh to the remote separately? You might need to add your local public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys